# is filehelper library able to read xml files

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, filehelpers

I am using filehelpers library to read and write csv files in my .net project. I need to read and write xml files also using the same library. is it possible with filehelpers library.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileHelpers does not parse XML files, it parses fixed width and CSV files.  XML parsing can be handled with the standard .NET libraries to create a data table.  FileHelpers can then write out that data table to a CSV or Text file